# Get Latest Post To Show on Home Page with Eleventy

Tags: static-site, nunjucks, eleventy, static-site-generation

I'm diving into the static site generators and trying to build a blog out using the basic eleventy blog:
https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog

So far, everything is good, but I'm wondering how to go about to get it to show the latest post on the home/index page.

Right out of the box, it will show the 3 latest links to the posts using nunjucks:

```
{% set postslist = collections.posts | head(-3) %}
{% set postslistCounter = collections.posts | length %}
{% include "postslist.njk" %}
```

But what I'm wondering how to get the latest markdown post from the `posts` directory and see if it can pull that to render.

I am thinking that there's got to be a way to check the date within nunjucks like this (I know this is wrong, but trying to get an idea):

```
{% if post.date = currdate %}
{% include "posts.njk" %}
{% endif %}
```

Anyways, I know it's possible, but I'm still trying to learn and looking to get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could work for you:

```html
{% set postslist = collections.posts | head(-3) %}

<h1>Latest Post</h1>
{{ postslist[0].templateContent | safe }}
```

I basically just use the templateContent variable of the first post. I moved that set command higher in the template so I could use another H3. Here's my entire file:

```html
---
layout: layouts/home.njk
eleventyNavigation:
  key: Home
  order: 1
---

{% set postslist = collections.posts | head(-3) %}

<h1>Latest Post</h1>
{{ postslist[0].templateContent | safe }}

<h1>Latest 3 Posts</h1>

{% set postslistCounter = collections.posts | length %}
{% include "postslist.njk" %}

<p>More posts can be found in <a href="{{ '/posts/' | url }}">the archive</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Sorry for the delay. Been busy and finally getting around to this. I'll mess around with this today.

Comment: No worries - enjoy. (And if it works, accept the answer please. :)

Comment: I was able to get this to work by doing this:
https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog/issues/78#issuecomment-712120241
Looks like it was a combination of both, but for the most part, it was the `{% set postslist = collections.posts | head(-3) %}` that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is outdated, because Nunjucks removed the built-in `head` filter. You can use `first` filter to select the most recent blog post like this:

```
{% set mostRecent = collections.posts | first %}
```

To select the first (or last) `n` posts, loop over `collections.posts`:

```
{% set top = 3 %}
{% for post in collections.posts %}
  {# ensure that top does not exceed the length of the collection #}
  {% if (loop.index <= top) and (top <= loop.length) %}
    <div>{{ post.title }}</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Use the `reverse` filter for the other direction.

See also: http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for